# Music service crash on rotate

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-music-player

I'm trying to incorporate code from [create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback--mobile-22778) into my app but the service is crashing on rotation of the device.

in the activity...

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (playIntent == null) {
        playIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
        bindService(playIntent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        startService(playIntent);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    stopPlay();
    musicSrv = null;
    playIntent = null;
    unbindService(musicConnection);
    super.onStop();
}

private void stopPlay() {
    if (musicSrv != null)
        musicSrv.stop();
}
```

in the service ... **[UPDATE added in onCreate and onDestroy for lifecylce of player]**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    songPosn = 0;
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    initMusicPlayer();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
    player = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void initMusicPlayer(){
    // set player properties
    player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    player.setOnErrorListener(this);
}


public void stop() {
    if (player != null)
        player.stop(); // << this line crashes after second rotation
}

public void playSong() {
    // play a song
    player.reset(); // << this line crashes after rotation and play
    Song playSong = songs.get(songPosn);
    long currSong = playSong.mId;
    Uri trackUri = playSong.getUri();

    try {
        player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), trackUri);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
    }
    player.prepareAsync();
}
```

**[UPDATE added logcat]**

```
2019-02-01 14:20:56.756 11217-11243/com.mycompany.myapp I/Adreno: Build Config                     : S L 4.0.10 AArch64
2019-02-01 14:20:56.760 11217-11243/com.mycompany.myapp I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff110, ME: 0x005ff066
2019-02-01 14:20:56.766 11217-11243/com.mycompany.myapp I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-02-01 14:20:56.767 11217-11243/com.mycompany.myapp I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-02-01 14:20:56.769 11217-11243/com.mycompany.myapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-02-01 14:20:56.769 11217-11243/com.mycompany.myapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2019-02-01 14:20:56.889 11217-11217/com.mycompany.myapp D/CalRecycler: Calendar Count = 1
2019-02-01 14:20:56.890 11217-11217/com.mycompany.myapp I/chatty: uid=10204(com.mycompany.myapp) identical 1 line
2019-02-01 14:20:56.892 11217-11217/com.mycompany.myapp D/CalRecycler: Calendar Count = 1
2019-02-01 14:21:04.798 11217-11217/com.mycompany.myapp D/MusicService: onUnbind: 
2019-02-01 14:21:04.799 11217-11217/com.mycompany.myapp E/MediaPlayerNative: stop called in state 1, mPlayer(0x0)
2019-02-01 14:21:04.799 11217-11217/com.mycompany.myapp E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2019-02-01 14:21:04.811 11217-11217/com.mycompany.myapp V/MediaPlayer: resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
2019-02-01 14:21:04.811 11217-11217/com.mycompany.myapp V/MediaPlayer: cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
2019-02-01 14:21:04.944 11217-11217/com.mycompany.myapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 507 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2019-02-01 14:21:05.072 11217-11243/com.mycompany.myapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=8590ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=626379375911582, Vsync=626387825911244, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=626387838413745, AnimationStart=626387838658172, PerformTraversalsStart=626387842406401, DrawStart=626387863394893, SyncQueued=626387940397609, SyncStart=626387940670057, IssueDrawCommandsStart=626387941099744, SwapBuffers=626387960066205, FrameCompleted=626387966297195, DequeueBufferDuration=409000, QueueBufferDuration=357000, 
2019-02-01 14:21:05.111 11217-11217/com.mycompany.myapp W/MediaPlayer: mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
2019-02-01 14:21:15.280 11217-11217/com.mycompany.myapp D/MainActivity: onPause
2019-02-01 14:21:15.287 11217-11217/com.mycompany.myapp D/MainActivity: onStop
2019-02-01 14:21:15.288 11217-11217/com.mycompany.myapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-02-01 14:21:15.306 11217-11217/com.mycompany.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mycompany.myapp, PID: 11217
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnStop(ActivityThread.java:4189)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4796)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4732)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaPlayer._reset(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.reset(MediaPlayer.java:2178)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.util.MusicService.stop(MusicService.java:93)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity.stopPlay(MainActivity.java:300)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity.onStop(MainActivity.java:140)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1432)
    at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:7375)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnStop(ActivityThread.java:4181)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4796) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4732) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2019-02-01 14:21:15.349 11217-11217/com.mycompany.myapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11217 SIG: 9
```

I've been looking at several posts about IllegalStateException but I don't see any that address the rotation aspect. I've tried moving the code from `onStart` to `onResume` and `onStop` to `onPause` but no luck. One thing that's strange is that it works on the first rotation but crashes for the second rotation. During the first rotation I see `E/MediaPlayerNative: stop called in state 1, mPlayer(0x0)` and `E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)`. This occurs *after* the onResume but it doesn't crash at this point. It crashes if I rotate it again or if I try to use the service and play a song.

**[UPDATE added attempt to suppress cofig change]**

```
<application
    android:name=".util.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

That didn't work.

Any ideas? Anyone out there who have successfully created their own music service? Need additional code from my app? BTW - I'm using a service because I also want to use it from a receiver.

TIA, Mike

Comment: Android recreates the activity whenever its rotated, maybe its crashing because you are trying to start a service which has already been stopped.
also could be that you're binding a stopped service.

Comment: How much time passes betweeen the two rotations?

Comment: @ivan I'm aware the activity is dumped and re-created. That's why I included the `onStop` and `onStart` code from the activity. You can see that I'm unbinding the existing one in the `onStop`, setting the `playIntent` to null, and then creating a new one in the `onStart`.

Comment: @0X0nosugar I have been waiting just five seconds or so, but after your comment I just tried it with a 30 count and it still crashed.

Comment: Then I think it's best if you share the crash log and more (but as little as possible, I know audio player code can get quite long) of the code for the Service. For example we can't see how/ where *player* is initiated.

Comment: I updated the question to include lifecycle events and logcat. They're marked

Comment: OK, I'll get back to you if I find something (it's getting a bit late around here)

Comment: just put this in the activities props in manifest and stop the lifeCycle Restart issue
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize", then you wont even need the onStop and onDestroy to do something for you!

Comment: lemme know if this helps or bugs still bugs out

Comment: @Rizwanatta That setting didn't have any affect. The Activity is still being disposed and re-created... and still crashes

Comment: can you show how did you put the config change in your manifest file please!

Comment: read out on this too for lifeCycle config changes https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#ConfigurationChanges

Comment: @Rizwanatta I updated the question with what I tried in the manifest. Thanks for the link on config changes. That was news to me.

Comment: @Mike i see you have put it wrong check mine answer below you should put it as activity prop! as i have mentioned and the problem should not persist even you can get rid of onDestroy and onStop. upvote and accept the answer it will help.

Comment: @Rizwanatta Yeah, I saw that. I added it into the activities and that fixed it for that activity. However when I navigate to a different activity and then back again the issue is raised again. This time if I try to play a sound on the main. So without any rotation, I start a new activity, then hit the back button, and play something. Croak.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187772/discussion-between-rizwan-atta-and-mike).

Comment: Something I just noticed. The service's onUnbind function runs *AFTER* the entire lifecycle changeover. `onPause -> onStop -> onStart -> onResume` and *then* the onUnbind runs. Is it unbinding the wrong one because of garbage collection in idle time?

Answer (score 1):

For getting rid of the restart problem Just put this in the **activities props** in manifest and stop the lifeCycle Restart issue android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize", then you wont even need the onStop and onDestroy to do something for you!

> by ActivityProp I mean to say . the starting tag of the activity
>   properties like shown below in the code

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard" <=== add like this
   >

      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

for more related to configuration changes see this link please
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#ConfigurationChanges

Comment: This setting prevents it from crashing on rotation however there are still issues. We removed the service related code from the life cycle functions but I'm still left with a crash. When I back out of the app and re-enter, then try to play... crash. :(